# how to calculate total time for one request from chrome driver PERFORMANCE logs?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on selenium to track network traffic for website.

I have followed referred two links:

1. [Using Selenium how to get network request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847035/using-selenium-how-to-get-network-request)
2. http://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging/performance-log

I got log data as after configuration.
you can refer point 2 for example data:
Here is what i got

```json
[2015-03-21T16:50:20+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Network.responseReceived","params":{"frameId":"28480.1","loaderId":"28480.2","requestId":"28480.1","response":{"connectionId":0,"connectionReused":false,"encodedDataLength":-1,"fromDiskCache":false,"fromServiceWorker":false,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Content-Type":"text/plain;charset=US-ASCII"},"mimeType":"text/plain","protocol":"data","status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"data:,"},"timestamp":1426942217.5344,"type":"Other"}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
[2015-03-21T16:50:20+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Network.loadingFinished","params":{"encodedDataLength":0,"requestId":"28480.1","timestamp":1426942217.5344}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
[2015-03-21T16:50:20+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Page.frameNavigated","params":{"frame":{"id":"28480.1","loaderId":"28480.2","mimeType":"text/plain","securityOrigin":"://","url":"data:,"}}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
[2015-03-21T16:50:21+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":1426942220.99924}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
[2015-03-21T16:50:21+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Page.frameStoppedLoading","params":{"frameId":"28480.1"}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
[2015-03-21T16:50:21+0400] [INFO] {"message":{"method":"Page.domContentEventFired","params":{"timestamp":1426942220.99927}},"webview":"C359224A-06E5-42B6-8D1B-52687733920A"}
....
```

But i dont know how to calculate time of one request xhr request?

I have searched for it but now luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each log entry, the total time taken to complete a request is :
`message.params.response.timing.sendStart - message.params.response.timing.sendEnd`.

The performance log should be filtered for only those messages which have `message.method = "Network.responseReceived"`.

---

Regarding understanding `message.params.response.timing` section, for instance something as follows:

```json
{"message": {
    ...
     "params": {
        ...
          "response": {
             "timing": {
                 "sendEnd": 1.132,
                 "sendStart": 0.96,
                 ...
        },
        "url": "https://example.com/GetBlah"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

look here: https://groups.google.com/g/google-chrome-developer-tools/c/FCCV2J7BaIY

---

After enabling the PERFORMANCE logs, you can iterate the log entries using:

```
List<LogEntry> entries = this.driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll();
```

Then, you can get the json with the following values:

```
private String url;
private Boolean timing;
private Long connectEnd;
private Long connectStart;
private Long dnsEnd;
private Long dnsStart;
private Long receiveHeadersEnd;
private Long sslStart;
private Long sslEnd;
private Long proxyStart;
private Long proxyEnd;
private Long sendStart;
private Long sendEnd;
private String mimeType;
private String requestStatus;
private String method;
```

to get the total time for a single request you can use:

`sendStart - sendEnd`

Creation of the Chrome Driver:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

    Map<String, Object> perfLogPrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    perfLogPrefs.put("traceCategories", "browser,devtools.timeline,devtools");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("perfLoggingPrefs", perfLogPrefs);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: there are mutliple methods in logs like requestwillbesent, responsereceived In which log data i can get sendStart and sendEnd

Comment: Above code should give you all the values mentioned. Are you getting anything else?

Comment: yes, all you have mentioned can be get in log message which has method Network.requestResponseReceived. But ihave not seen SendStart and sendEnd in it hence asking

Comment: this is the method I'm using: Network.responseReceived. also edited the answer with more code

Comment: `sendStart` and `sendEnd` are seconds or milliseconds?