# Selenium Test background screen when a timeout popup occurs

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a selenium test for an Angular web application using Java.

**Usecase to test :**  We have a data table grid which refreshes every 20 seconds (basically makes an rest api call to refresh data). In case the user/screen is idle for sometime a timeout modal dialog is shown.
When the timeout modal dialog appears, the datagrid table refresh is stopped. And nothing in the background is accessible (nothing can be clicked except the modal dialog).

How can I test the below scenarios?

1. When modal dialog appears. TO test, No refresh is happening on the datagrid.
2. When modal dialog appears. TO test, Nothing else is accessible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second test,
you can check that the other elements except for the dialog has a property such as ```disabled``` set as true or ```enabled``` set as false.
And for the first case,
Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847035/using-selenium-how-to-get-network-request]

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem