# Finding the API hit count and resource downloaded size in browser

Tags: python, api, browser

Is there a way I can get the number of API's been hit and the amount of data downloaded by the browser when a page is loading?

I like to get the amount of data downloaded and the count using i.e Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) can help you with this. There is a post in which the use Selenium to get the network requests: [Using Selenium how to get network request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847035/using-selenium-how-to-get-network-request)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can export [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) file from your [favorite browser](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting) and analyse it via python. HAR is just a JSON file so you can implement a script that will look for the data you are interested in.