# Can I know which API was called in the backend when a button or some action was performed?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, python-responses

Actually I'm writing an automation script in selenium with python. I'm am trying to get an id which is attached in the API's url which is hit only after an action is performed. To be more clear:

- There's a button in the grid, when clicked a get API is hit
- Eg :`abc.com/test?id=123456789`  this is an example of API which is hit only when the button is clicked. I need to get this API's url so that I can split it to get that "id=123456789".

Comment: when the action is performed, do you see any changes in HTML ? to be more precise in DOM ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847035/using-selenium-how-to-get-network-request/60060074

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi, yes there is changes in DOM. On performing the action(here the button was clicked) opens a popup

Comment: Can you share the HTML code when it's changed  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey before the button is clicked it has `<body class="Menu">......</body>` and when the button is clicked series of div class are added including a change in`<body class="Menu modal-open>......</body> `